# The difference between two algebraic sets is not closed?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, semialgebraic-geometry

Let $A$ and $B$ be two non-empty algebraic subsets of $\mathbb{C}^n$ such that $B$ is strictly contained in $A$. I am trying to show that the difference $A-B$, which is a semi-algebraic set, is not closed for the Euclidean topology. Of course if $A$ is finite then the answer is negative. However, if we suppose that the interior of $A$ is non-empty, can we show that it is not closed?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't knwo about algebraic subsets but take $A =[\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4}] \cup \mathbb{Z}$ and $B = \mathbb{Z}$ note that $A$ has non-empty interior. The difference is the closed interval which *is* closed. So if it is at all true, it must be due to the sets being "algebraic" whatever that means.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $\mathbb{C}$, The real numbers $\mathbb{R}$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb{C}$, and the single point $x=(0,0)$ is a closed subset of the $\mathbb{C}$ contained in $\mathbb{R}$, remove it from $\mathbb{R}$, then the remaining set is not closed as $x$ would be a limit point of it, not in that set!

Comment: Thank you! Yes in this example it is not closed. But my question is if it is always not closed?

Answer (score 1):

If $A-B$ denotes set difference $A \setminus B$, let $A$,$B$ be closed and suppose $A\setminus B$ is closed: this happens precisely when $B$ is open in $A$. So there are plenty of positive examples: if $A$ is closed and discrete, for any subset $B$ of $A$ we have that $B$ is closed and $A \setminus B$ is closed (e.g. $A = \mathbb{Z} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ would work. But for $A =X$ we get that if $A \setminus B$ is closed and $B$ is closed, $B$ would be clopen and so in Euclidean spaces (or any connected $X$) this would happen iff $B =\emptyset$ or $B=X$. So it could be closed or not, the most "likely" being not closed.

Comment: Would it suffice to impose the condition that all connected components of $A$ contain infinitely many points to prevent $A\setminus B$ from being closed?

Comment: Thank you! The situation is now clearer to me. But I am still not sure about the sufficient conditions which have to be added to ensure that the difference is not closed? Maybe what @SeverinSchraven said works? Also I think that $B$ does not have to be a connected component of $A$.

Comment: The condition on closed $A$ and $B$ not having a closed difference is just "$A \setminus B$ is not closed" :) (it's certainly closed when $B$ is open besides closed, e.g. ). I don't really see how that could be simplified. Why are you interested in such sufficient conditions anyway @joe?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I want to apply the "lemme des petits chemins" on a point which belongs to the closure of some semi-algebraic set $S=A\setminus B$ but not in $S$ (the lemma can be applied for any point in the closure). For such a point to exist, $S$ must be not closed. This is why I am interested in knowing which conditions have to be imposed on $A$ and $B$ to ensure that $S$ is not closed.